# Smoothing potential 30kHz noise in battery "switcher"?

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, diodes, noise, fet

I've created a circuit that switches individual  items of avionics (for my glider) between two 12V batteries. The idea is that I can switch items between battery A or B depending on how the batteries (and my power requirements) hold up over the course of a flight.

There are five individual instruments. They nominally draw from 100 - 500 mA, but some (the radio in particular) could spike up to 5A. wiring is specified for at least 5A, and each output has a 3A fuse (aside from the radio, which has 5A).

I originally started with the following circuit (the diagram shows 2 functional blocks of the five) -- 5 groups of P-channel FETs. Instruments are switched on, and between batteries, with individual on-off-on toggle switches at the gate of each FET. Capacitors at the gate provide enough debounce to prevent power cutting out when switches are moved from position A, through off, to position B.

[image: two of 5 switching blocks]

This circuit works fine, but I neglected to notice the bypass diodes on each FET. This means that, if one battery depletes  significantly more than the other (or if,  for example, one battery is not connected), current from one battery circuit makes it into the other. I'd like to avoid this.

The obvious solution is two diodes at each output, but as battery capacity is at a premium in a glider, I'd like to avoid the voltage drop.  I'm considering adding two [of these (SM74611)](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/sm74611kttr/hot-swap-controller-30v-to-263/dp/2492333) to each output, as they have the lowest voltage drop I can find. However, the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=SM74611&&fileType=pdf) suggests that the voltage drop spikes periodically, with a frequency of about 30kHz / duty cycle 99%.

I'd like to avoid sending this spike off down wires to the instruments -- not that they can't handle it (they're designed to accept unregulated 12V from batteries), but to avoid the potential associated noise, which could impact sensitive radio / FLARM antennae.

Will it be enough to stick electrolytic caps across each output, or should I be looking at a full-on LC filter? Or am I barking up the wrong tree altogether?

Any and all advice much appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering why your glier receiver is taking 5 amps.

Comment: It doesn't... with everything on at once, I see around 100mA draw... but the radio manual (and various other sources) say that it can peak at over 3A... I assume when transmitting.

Comment: Why not use the switches to switch the power directly, without the MOSFETs?

Comment: They're pretty small switches... not many decent sized title switches can switchelp 12v dc at up to 5A... and I still need to debounce the switch / maintain power during the crossover.